# Excel VBA with Outlook: How to use AdvancedSearch method to search for specific emails in Outlook?

Tags: excel, email, outlook, vba

I have a program here that searches thru each emails in Sent Items folder of Outlook until it finds the tag(URL) in the specified email, opens it and sends a reply.

But I have a lot of emails inside the Sent Items folder, so it's taking so much time for searching thru each emails.

I've read that AdvancedSearch method is a faster way for searching specific emails. But I don't really know how it works that's why I need your help guys.

**How do I use AdvancedSearch method with this type of program?**

Appreciate your help guys.

```
Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = olNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)

For Each olMail In olFolder.Items

    tagLink = Sheets("Data").Cells(rowCount, 6)

    If InStr(olMail.HTMLBody, tagLink) <> 0 Then

    With olMail.Reply

        .Display
        .To = sMailTo
        .CC = sMailCC
        .HTMLBody = mailBody & vbLf & .HTMLBody

        .Send

    End With

    End If

Next olMail
```

Answer (score 0):

> For Each olMail In olFolder.Items

Don't iterate over all items in the folder. Especially if you have got a huge amount of items in the folder.

Instead, you may consider using the Restrict or Find/FindNext methods of the Items class. You may find them described in depth in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

And of course you may consider using the `AdvancedSearch` method of the Application class. The main benefit of using this method is the ability to get search running in the background and search for items in deferent/multiple folders. Read more about all the benefits in the [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) article.

Finally, you may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article helpful.